# Representing a class diagram using protege

Tags: sparql, ontology, class-diagram, protege

I'm developing an ontology for a searching laboratory and I need to represent my class diagram with "Protege". I don't know how to represent relations cardinals. How can I do it for this one for example?

[image]

And what about the cardinals :
0...*

2..5

3..*

0..1

etc

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that an instance of Faculty teaches at exactly one University, you'd use a property restriction and a subclass axiom:

(1)        Faculty **SubClassOf** (teachesAt **exactly 1** University)

To say that *at least* one instance of Faculty teaches at every University, you'd use another peoperty restriction and a subclass axiom, but you'll need to use the inverse property:

(2)        University **SubClassOf** (**inverse**(teachesAt) **min 1** University)

If you prefer, you can use **some** instead of **min 1** in axiom (2).

In general, there are a few restrictions that will impose cardinalities:

- **some** (at least one (equivalent to **min 1**))
- **min n** (at least *n*)
- **max n** (at most *n*)
- **exactly n** (exactly *n*)

So for some other ranges, you could say things like:

- Mammals have between two and four (2..4) legs:
  Mammal **SubClassOf** ((hasLegs **min 2**) **and** (hasLegs **max 4**))
- Forests have at least 300 (300..) trees:
  Forest **SubClassOf** hasTree **min 300**
- Cars have at most one (0..1) radio:
  Car **SubClassOf** hasRadio **max 1**